# How do I tabulate moderators based on various statistics (close/delete requests, reputationm etc)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

SO elections are on and there's a lot of jibber jabber: how do I get a table of moderators with the lowest delete/close posts and the maximum of edits? How do I tabulate based on actual work they do, rather than rely on what they say about themselves - though I intend to read that as well. Why do this manually with paper and pen, when software can generate this for us.

I want a sorted table to avoid lopsided candidates - I'm not going to blindly pick the lowest deletes. I'm looking for a table where I can sort on columns of my choosing, and once I isolate a few suitable choices I can zoom in and read the blurb.

Comment: (Andy on chat suggested this: http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow but it's still a pain since i can't click sort on common criteria)

Comment: Why would you want to know very lopsided candidates?

Comment: There is no public count of close or delete votes cast by a user. With some work, you can extract the number of questions that the user successfully closed; but to my understanding this requires downloading and parsing SEDE output, since the closevoters data is stored as a JSON string in one of fields. Nothing that's really easy.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/286784/close-votes-by-user-with-links is one seemingly useful query, though the date filter doesn't work for me.